# Calling fragment from a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a fragment that shows a dialog after guessing correctly the answer.
What do I need to do to call the NEXT fragment upon clicking Next on the dialog? Thanks

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setTitle("Well done")
            .setMessage("That is correct! \n Click next to continue")
            .setPositiveButton("Next", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                       ????? ?????????
                       ????? ?????????



                }
            })
            .setIcon(R.drawable.img_apple)
            .show();
```

Comment: Are you using viewpager..?

Comment: Yes, I am using a Viewpager in my Main class